# Binding object collection to DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to bind a collection of objects to a datagrid as follows:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectCollection}" DataContext="Binding"
```

however this seems to do nothing. In code I also have the following:

```
gridData.ItemsSource = ObjectCollection;
```

When I run this code it throws no errors however does not achieve the functionality required as the data is not binded. As well as this I get an error message as follows:

```
BindingExpression path error: 'ObjectCollection' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-1908995926)'. BindingExpression:Path=ObjectCollection; DataItem='String' (HashCode=-1908995926); target element is 'DataGrid' (Name='gridData'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
```

Any ideas on what the issue is? Have been at it all day.

Comment: What is the type of your ObjectCollection

Comment: Is that your original code? `DataContext="Binding"` It does not have the `{}`.

Comment: I think the error occurred because your `DataContext` binding is wrong. it cannot find a `String` type `DataContext`.

Comment: If the DataContext is itself, it should be `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`

Comment: The type of my objectcollection is an observable collection of a class called collectionobject with varying attributes. To answer the other question the code is my predecessor's so I apologise for the variable names.

Comment: So is your `DataContext` correct?

Comment: Please edit your question and post entire xaml and xaml.cs code.